# Telerik Silverlight RadGrid Skin

Tags: silverlight, grid, skin

Could anyone please let me know how to change the skin of a Telerik silverlight radgrid control programatically.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add all of the necessary Telerik theme .dll's and you can do it by setting the StyleManager.ApplicationTheme.

```
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestingTelerikSilverlightControls
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new SummerTheme();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```